# PHP MYSQL получить значения из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, мне нужно получить все поля из таблицы **comments**. В таблице **comments** есть поле **answerid**. Так вот ещё мне нужно в таблице **answers**, получить значения поля `questionid`, где `answers id = comments answerid`.

То есть в комментариях есть id ответа, а в ответе есть id вопроса. И кроме комментария и его полей, мне нужно получить id вопроса к которому относится ответ под которым мы оставили комментарий

Я сделал это так:

```
    "SELECT * FROM answers, comments WHERE comments.answerid = answers.id
   AND comments.userid = {$i} ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Но мне не нравится что запрос выбирает всё из answers, так как мне нужно взять оттуда всего лишь одно поле **questionid**. Не подскажите как можно изменить запрос?

Comment: А что вам мешает сделать "SELECT answers.questionid, comments.* ....

Comment: @Arsen спасибо, это то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

`SELECT a.questionid, c.* FROM answers a, comments c WHERE c.answerid = a.id AND c.userid = {$i} ORDER BY c.id DESC LIMIT 10`